# How to stop someone in a wheelchair from calling in paramedics for minor accidents?

Tags: conversations, conflict-aversion, united-kingdom, disability

Someone I know quite closely quite enjoys the attention of paramedics. She is an amputee, is currently unemployed, and is very attention-centric.

Every time she has a minor accident, she calls over paramedics. What can we do to stop her doing this?

Comment: How do they call paramedics? By calling an emergency number, or are they living in a care facility? Are you involved in her care? Who's 'we'?

Comment: @apaul The United Kingdom

Comment: @Tinkeringbell They live alone, I'm related to her, but not actively involved in her care. I'm not usually the one burdened by this, but someone I know is (they take it upon themselves).

Comment: What burdens does calling the paramedics cause that you want to address? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jesse Calling paramedics when it is not needed puts burdens on the paramedics, and puts a burden on everyone who actually _needs_ paramedics and has to wait longer because of a selfish attention seeker. And that is what the OP has to make clear to that person: That their selfish actions have consequences, and every time they call out paramedics with no good reason, someone else with an actual need has to wait longer.

Answer (score 5):

Likely the easiest way to handle this will be the honest way.

Just tell them the truth:

> If you keep calling paramedics when it isn't strictly necessary, sooner or later they're going to get social services involved, if they haven't already. If it continues they may even force you into a residential care facility.

Paramedics tend to take their time and resources very very seriously and don't take it lightly if they feel like their time and resources are being wasted. Chances are pretty good that if they've been called out to the same address several times they've already made note of it and either already have had this conversation with them, or will before too long. Rest assured that if you don't want to get involved in explaining it, you won't need to. The paramedics will.